# Pub/Sub on Android via Google Sign-in

Tags: android, google-signin, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to use [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) in my Android app. The main problem is that I can't use `creds.json` in the project. Instead I'd like to use authenification/authorization like I do it when I use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides). Maybe somebody knows how to do that or can say me that it is imposible.

Let me explain what I have and what I'd like to have.

I have an email client that uses [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) to work with messages. I use [Google Sign](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) for authentication.

For now, to check for new messages I use [CoroutineWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker) that uses [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) for execution.

Based on docs `Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes.` But I'd like to receive updates more frequently and don't do a lot of requests.

I've found that [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) can use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

I've done the preparation and I'm able to get updates via [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) functionality. My Android app can subscribe for updates.

The worked code looks like this

```
implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.123.7')
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.54.0'
```

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try {
        val subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of("myproject", "my-sub")
        val subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName,
          MessageReceiver { message, _ ->
            Log.d("PUBSUB", "message = ${message?.data?.toStringUtf8()}")
          })
          .setCredentialsProvider {
            GoogleCredentials.fromStream(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.creds))
          }
          .build()
        subscriber?.startAsync()?.awaitRunning()
        subscriber?.awaitTerminated()
      } catch (t: Throwable) {
        t.printStackTrace()
        Log.i("PUBSUB", t.message ?: "Something went wrong")
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribing to Cloud Pub/Sub via Android devices would be considered an anti-pattern. As you noted, the authentication model is not conducive to using Google sign-on for authenticating. Additionally, the limits on number of resources in Pub/Sub (10,000 subscriptions per topic or per project) mean that you'd only be able to support that many devices/users.

Instead, you'd want to connect the Pub/Sub subscription to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to send the notifications to the end user devices. You can [trigger a function when a message is published to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) and then send a notification to a device.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm going to investigate this way.